# Restore verifyonly for many databases

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, backup, database-backups

```
DECLARE @backupSetId INT
DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(max)
SET @URL = ''

SELECT @backupSetId = position 
FROM msdb..backupset 
WHERE database_name = N'database name' 
  AND backup_set_id = (SELECT MAX(backup_set_id) 
                       FROM msdb..backupset 
                       WHERE database_name = N'database name')

IF @backupSetId IS NULL
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database '
'myActions'' not      found.', 16, 1) 

END

RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
FROM @URL'n'
WITH FILE = @backupSetId,  checksum
GO
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to run a sepate job to restore verifyonly for all the databases backup

Comment: Declare another variable, write your select as dynamic sql, use the variable for your database_name.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: This is where I am having difficulties of doing that. getting information of all the databases if they are restore verifyable.

Comment: @JacobH, can you give me how, i can't think of it. Thanks and new to this.

Comment: Your requirements are still a bit unclear. Do you want the procedure to run VERIFYONLY against every db on the server? Or do you want to run the proc with a db name as the input?

Comment: @JacobH, I want the procedure to run verifyonly against every db on the server.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting backupsetid = position? Is this query functioning as is? Do you plan on passing the backup location as part of the procedure? How where/are the backups stored?

Comment: @JacobH, I am planning to pas backup location as part of the procedure. Backup stored in windows azure blob storage.

Comment: If you are passing one URL to the procedure, then you would need to run the procedure each time for each database right? Just making sure you aren't expecting the procedure to run once for all databases.

Comment: @JacobH, all the backup take place in same storage pool, so it should be fine.

Comment: @JacobH, want to excludes system databases like master, model, msdb, and tempdb?

Comment: @JacobH, manager didn't like that it was dynamical sql. he want to use non-dynamical sql for it.

Comment: What's your manager's plan then?

Comment: @JacobH, working with initial script that i post and do similar for all the databases. Right that script does for one db not for all dbs. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting an answer, but I am not 100% confident if this will work for you successfully as I don't have backups in a virtual storage pool for testing. I am also cheating a bit by using the database id as the row number (@Loop). Same with the database count (since I also don't know this). That could be done more gracefully. Hopefully this at least leads you in the right direction though:

```
DECLARE @backupSetId INT
DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Loop int = 1
DECLARE @NumberOfDBs int = 0

SET @URL = ''

SET @NumberOfDBs = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases)

WHILE @Loop <= @NumberOfDBs
BEGIN

    SET @DatabaseName = (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = @Loop)

    EXEC sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT @backupSetId = position 
    FROM msdb..backupset 
    WHERE database_name = N''@DatabaseName'' 
    AND backup_set_id = (SELECT MAX(backup_set_id) 
                   FROM msdb..backupset 
                   WHERE database_name = N''@DatabaseName'')'

    IF @backupSetId IS NULL
        BEGIN 
             RAISERROR(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''myActions'' not      found.', 16, 1) 
        END




RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
FROM @URL
WITH FILE = @backupSetId,  checksum

SET @Loop = @Loop +1
END
```

Comment: @Jacon H, this include system databases as well. I want to exclude that.

Comment: Set the @Loop declaration to 5 instead of 1 (or whatever database you want to start at, system databases are 1-4 on my system).

Comment: Did it work successfully? I know using the database id as the loop variable isn't really the best, there are definitely better ways to do that.